# Bash incrementing bash string - from text file

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am struggling to get a piece of my code working. I have a database with usernames in it and the script automatically chooses the next available username. For example input is `JoeBlogs` but `JoeBlogs` is already taken so `JoeBlogs1` is used, then `JoeBlogs2` etc. The database contains the list of used usernames so I am trying to get it to put the next number availible after the given name.

```bsh
testdb=`cat test.db`
cd "$(dirname "$0")"
ftpfullname="JoeBlogs"
for output in $testdb
do
    if [ "$ftpfullname" == "$output" ]
    then
        ftpfullname="${ftpfullname}1"
    fi
done
echo "$ftpfullname has been selected"
```

`test.db` is very simple, just a bunch of names stored on their own line.

I understand why it's not working I just can't work out how to do it.

Comment: It seems your `for` loop is not incrementing. Put an `printf` instruction within it to see if it's working (As `printf $output` by example)

Comment: It would help if you tell us your understanding of why it's not working.

Comment: Tell us how  your `test.db` is constructed / updated, and be more specific than *"its not working"*

Comment: @Redbob Just in case the output might contain printf format strings or globs, you should use either `echo "$output"` or `printf '%s' "$output"`.

Comment: @steeldriver its very simple just a list of names

Comment: But the result when "JoeBlogs1" is found will be "JoeBlogs11", not JoeBlogs2, according to your code block

Comment: @Redbob exactly, I tried to work it out for the last 5 hours and I can't get it to work. I even tried using recursive loops and arrays but I can't seem to crack it. I have hit a brick wall and any help would be greatly appreciated. JoeBlogs2 is the required outcome. However, if that already exists as well it would then be JoeBlogs3 etc...

Comment: Is `testdb` sorted alphabetically?

Comment: Within `if` statement, you should extract last character and test if it's numeric. if so, increase it by 1 and append to first part of $output. The issue will be when it reaches 10.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix no but it could be, you'll have to forgive me as I am not very experienced?

Comment: @Redbob can I do that by piping it to the awk command?

Comment: `awk`is not so familiar to me.. but I believe it's a good choice. @WJAndrea could tell it more properly. Is it?

Comment: @Redbob You can do this in Bash with regex.

Comment: thanks all for your advice, with your help I have managed to get it working!

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer below (just click [edit] and copy & paste to preserve the formatting) and accept it by clicking the tick next to it.

Comment: I agree with @dessert: please move the solution from your question post to a proper answer. I'm taking the liberty to remove it from the question. You can still access it through the [edit history](/posts/1002238/revisions).

Comment: Also: [useless use of backticks](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#backticks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
accountsdb=`cat test.db | sort`
namex="0"
nameplus=0
ftpfullname="turner"
for output in $accountsdb
do
  if [ "$ftpfullname" == "$output" ]
  then
    let "nameplus += 1"
    for i in $nameplus
    do
      echo "$nameplus"
      echo "$i"
      if [ "$namex" == "1" ]
      then
        ftpfullname=${ftpfullname%?}
      fi
      namex="1"
      ftpfullname="${ftpfullname}${i}"
      break
    done
  fi
done
echo "$ftpfullname"
echo $namex
echo "$ftpfullname" >> test.db
```

Comment: Just FYI, *never* use a `for` loop to iterate over a file, and certainly not `for line in $(cat file)`. You should instead use `while read line; do ... ;done < file`. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29